# determine wether IP adresses can refer to same network

Tags: web-services, ip

I'm analysing a database of web visits wanting to determine the number of different places users log in from using their IP address (if possible).

So my database looks something like this:

```
prospect_id| ip.address
0          | 187.130.68.177
0          | 187.145.151.43
0          | 187.145.201.74
0          | 187.152.184.243
```

I know the first two octates denote the network's address.

From such example, would my number be 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know the first two octates denote the network's address.

Not necessarily.

> From such example, would my number be 3?

You'll need to look them up on e.g. TCPIPUtils.com and check out the subnet range to find the "network's address".

- [187.130.68.177](http://www.tcpiputils.com/browse/ip-address/187.130.68.177) is in the range `187.130.64.0/19` (`187.130.64.0 - 187.130.95.255`).
- [187.145.151.43](http://www.tcpiputils.com/browse/ip-address/187.145.151.43) is in the range `187.145.128.0/19` (`187.145.128.0 - 187.145.159.255`).
- [187.145.201.74](http://www.tcpiputils.com/browse/ip-address/187.145.201.74) is in the range `187.145.192.0/19` (`187.145.192.0 - 187.145.223.255`).
- [187.152.184.243](http://www.tcpiputils.com/browse/ip-address/187.152.184.243) is in the range `187.152.160.0/19` (`187.152.160.0 - 187.152.191.255`).

However, the subnet only shows you the IP range and that all included IPs in the range belong to the same owner. To find the "administrative entity" that controls the ranges themselves you need to find the "[Autonomous System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(Internet))". All of the above are part of the [8151](http://www.tcpiputils.com/browse/as/8151) AS which is owned by [Uninet, S.A. de C.V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(Internet)).

> Uninet, S.A. de C.V. provides corporate networks and Internet access
>   services. The company is based in Ciudad De Mexico, Mexico. Uninet,
>   S.A. de C.V. operates as a subsidiary of Telefonos de Mexico, S.A.B.
>   de C.V.